# Calculate suscriptions in Power BI

Tags: dax

I have a problem building a pbi for a partner that has data of suscriptions of clients for 3 different products.

The table is start_date / end_date / id_person / suscription

I need to calculate a measure (or in a new column or a new table idc) that count the clients that has 1, 2 or 3 different suscriptions at the same time (you have to evaluate if they are currently suscribed). SO here is an example

```
start_date     end_date     id_person   suscription
  
01-03-2019       -            XXA          A

04-03-2019     07-09-2022     XXA          B

08-04-2021     09-04-2021     XXA          C

09-11-2023      -             XXA          B
```

So i want to make an indicator of what is this client XXA suscribed at that time, probably a concatenate or counter(idk). So for this example this client has to be counted as:

> from 01-03-2019 until 04-03-2019 as 'A'
>
> from 04-03-2019 to 08-04-2021 as 'AB'
>
> from 08-04-2021 to 09-04-2021 as 'ABC'
>
> from 09-04-2021 to 07-09-2022 as 'AB'
>
> from 07-09-2022 to 09-11-2023 as 'A'
>
> and from 09-11-2023 until now as 'AB'

so if i filter from all interval this client XXA has to be counted as 'AB'.

Please help i am struggling with this problem for days and I can't find a solution. Thank you so much!